# Make conenction between html span and button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i make a connection between html span and button- I want that when I press enter when the span is in focus, the html button will click and not another one(as happend to me rigth now)
thanks!

Comment: Provide your html and ask your question?

Comment: Could you provide us your current code?

Comment: Next time add you HTML for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

## Like this...

```js
var str='<a href="https://api.jquery.com/click/" >jquery\'s .click() function </a><br><br><a href="https://api.jquery.com/html/" >jquery\'s .html() function </a><br><br><a href="https://api.jquery.com/focus/" >jquery\'s .focus() function </a><br><br> <a href="https://api.jquery.com/keyup/" >jquery\'s .keyup() function </a><br><br>';

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#myspan').html(str);
});

// detect enter keypress in an input field
$('#field').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        $('#myspan').html(str);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myspan"></span><br>
<input type="button" value="Push me...." id="btn"/>
<input type="text" id="field" placeholder="or..type in me and press enter..." id="btn" size="55"/>
```

Comment: My problem is that I clicking 'Enter' after filling search span and another button is clicking and not the search button, how to fix it?

Comment: You say "search span" are you actually talking about a "text input"? Or are you using a content editable `<span>` tag?

Comment: And if you are talking about an input field, what button is pressed when you hit enter? Is this in a form and the button that gets clicked now is the form's submit button? Showing your html and javascript would help a lot.

Comment: @SagiGamil Edited to detect enter keypress in an input field